# SplashScreen not working on tablets (black screen)

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-videoview

I am writing an Android application and I have a video as the splash screen, but whenever I open the application on tablets, the screen goes black for the duration of the video. The splash screen works well on phones and on virtual devices (phone and tablet emulators), but on any physical tablet, only a black screen can be seen.

I have provided my manifest file and the java file for the splash screen. Am I doing something wrong? Are video splash screens treated differently than regular static photo splash screens?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myPackage">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".InfoActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".FixConditions"
        android:label=""
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".InfoActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".WebViewSignUp"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
VideoView videoView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.into);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            if (isFinishing())
                return;
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the specs of the physical tablet here?

Comment: My tablet is a Samsung galaxy tab4 (samsung sm t337a) with android version 5.1.1. But Im confident there is a problem in my code since the splash screen does not play on 3 different tablets (mine and two of my friends’) all of which have different specs.

Comment: @HernanDurah, I suggest to use a completely different approach, convert the video you are using to GIF (many free online software are available for that), easily populate the ImageView with GIF using **Glide Library**, The app will remain consistent across devices and the GIF will not change state on screen orientation, also GIF size is less than the video so the memory is also saved, the only drawback is that the quality of GIF will be lower, if quality of video is not a concern, I highly recommend you to follow GIF approach. - _Regards, Sankalp_

Comment: @Sankalp I tried your approach, but it did not work. After much debugging, I came to the conclusion it might be a problem with the video I want to use. I tried different video and the splash screen worked perfectly. Now my question is, what could the problem be with the video I actually want to use? These are the specs I am using: video codec : H.264 
file format: .mp4
video bitrate: 256kbps
video frame/second: 24

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the dimensions of the video. I had to change the width to 800 and height to 1280.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

to

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```